# mount error(13): Permission denied

Tags: server, mount, permissions, samba, fstab

I know this question has been asked before, but I've been looking for a solution for a couple of hours now and nothing seems to be working.

The frustrating thing is that it used to work on my previous install, so I know the commands I try should work.

I'm running a vanilla install of Ubuntu 13.04 server.

I have a server running at 192.168.1.130 and two shares: LaCie and Seagate 2TB.

I used to have these lines in my `fstab` file:

```
//192.168.1.130/Seagate\0402TB /home/Windows cifs user=admin,password=password,uid=1000 0 0
```

Now that I re-installed my server, but don't need it permanently I tried the following:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.130/LaCie ~/lacie -o user=admin
```

or

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o username='admin',password='<password>' //192.168.1.130/LaCie ~/lacie
```

However, I get the error `mount error(13): Permission denied`.

I'm sure the credentials are correct. Nothing has changed at the windows side.

Also, I installed the packages `samba`, `cifs-utils` too. Nothing helped.

Comment: Can you try `user=admin` instead of `username=admin`, and without the `'` apostrophe? Also, can you add the `user` option too? So `sudo mount -t cifs -o user,user=admin,password=password //192.168.1.130/LaCie ~/lacie`.

Comment: This `admin` user is a local user right? Maybe you need to add the workgroup or the domain to it. Also, [this thread over at the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1871142) seems to have a lot of info. Adding the option `sec=ntlm` or `sec=ntlmv2` seems to solve the issue for some.

Comment: Also, does this work if you prefix the command with sudo?

Comment: Allright, I've got the following command to work, but in /etc/fstab it's still nothing :(
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username='administrator',password='<pwd>' //192.168.1.130/seagate /home/seagate`

Comment: `//192.168.1.130/seagate /home/seagate cifs username=administrator,password=<pwd>,uid=1000 0 0` this solved the problem! (ie leave the quotation marks out!)

Comment: Hi @ChristopheDeTroyer! Can you please post this as an answer to the question? [You can answer your own question](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer); in fact, it is [encouraged to do so](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//192.168.1.130/seagate /home/seagate cifs username=administrator,password=<pwd>,uid=1000 0 0
```

This solved the problem! (i.e., leave the quotation marks out!)

Answer (score 13):

i had this same error. what solved it for me is reverting mount.cifs's security parameter back to its previous default as indicated [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=160047) and in mount.cifs' manpage:

> The default in mainline kernel versions prior to v3.8 was sec=ntlm. In v3.8, the default was changed to sec=ntlmssp.

in your case, the new command would be

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.130/LaCie ~/lacie -o user=admin,sec=ntlm
```

notice **sec=ntlm** at the end

Comment: Actually using `ntlmssp` solved it for me, as my default was already `ntlm`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This wasn't the problem in my case, but it pointed me to the real one - time lag on my Windows machine as described in my answer. +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it turned out to be time issues on the Windows machine - it has some problem where its time lags severely, in the range of 2 days per week (most likely the motherboard battery needs replacing). I manually updated the time and `mount` succeeded.

Arch Linux machine connecting to a Windows XP one, but I'd suspect it would be a problem for Ubuntu to newer Windowses as well.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS after upgrading and had the same problem

What I did to immediately remap the network folder was:

```
mount -t cifs //Server/Folder/ /mnt/MapedFolder -o domain=contoso.local,username=user,password=pass,sec=ntlm
```

Hope it helps others

Comment: The important missing param for me was sec=ntlm from an ARM running lubuntu, which I didnt need from a Fedora Desktop on x64

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the answers above, I was able to mount my Seagate personalCloud onto my raspberry Pi. I slightly tuned the commands above like this:

=> for the Public folder:
`sudo mount -t cifs -o noperm //192.168.1.x/Public /home/pi/Documents/PATH`

=> for the private folder (needs the username/pwd):
`sudo mount -t cifs -o username=<USERNMAE>,password=<PWD> //192.168.1.x/<PRIVATEFOLDERNAME> /home/pi/Documents/PATH`

I can now browse through the Seagate PersonalCloud like a normal disk!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well. I'm using centos (rpm based). I was getting `mount error(13): Permission denied` as well. Then I discovered that the problem was caused by SELinux (the lack of `public_content_t` context type) and of course the samba user `smbpasswd -a <user>` should have ownership of the directory.

- `semanage fcontext -a -t public_content_t "/mydir(/.*)?"` - adding public_content_t, verify using `ls -lZ`. Alternatively, turn off the selinux - `setenforce 0` (runtime), edit either `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` or `/etc/selinux/config` by adding/altering `SELINUX=disabled` (permanently)
- `chown :user1 /mydir && chmod +0070 /mydir` - giving an access for group, the member of which the samba user is.

Answer (score 0):

For me the fstab mount was failing because setting the `_netdev` option reports `eth0` up and running prior to dhcp completing.  This causes the mount to run prior to having an IP address from DHCP.

I'm using a raspberry pi on Jessie OS.  My solution was

```
sudo raspi-config
```

and selected the option 4 to wait for the network config to finish prior to finishing boot (and prior to mounting cifs folders).  Fixed it for me.  See also:  https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=124673

[image]

[image]